# value of local variable not used?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android app development, so this may be easy for you. I have searched this forum before I posted so please take a look before marking it as duplicate. I am not declaring static variables in the updatestandard method. Here is my program:

```
    package com.example.new1;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.SeekBar;
     import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
         public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   private static final String BILL_TOTAL = "BILL_TOTAL";
   private static final String CUSTOM_PERCENT = "CUSTOM_PERCENT";
   private double currentBillTotal; 
   private int currentCustomPercent;
   private EditText tip10EditText;
   private EditText total10EditText;
   private EditText tip15EditText; 
   private EditText total15EditText;
   private EditText billEditText; 
   private EditText tip20EditText; 
   private EditText total20EditText;
   private TextView customTipTextView;
   private EditText tipCustomEditText; 
   private EditText totalCustomEditText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if( savedInstanceState ==null)
    {
        currentBillTotal=0.0;
        currentCustomPercent=0;

    }
    else
    {
        currentBillTotal=savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_TOTAL);
        currentCustomPercent=savedInstanceState.getInt(CUSTOM_PERCENT);
    }
    tip10EditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip10editText);
    tip15EditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip15editText);
    tip20EditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip20editText);
    total10EditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.totaltenEditText);
    total20EditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.totaltwentyEditText);
    total15EditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalfifteenEditText);
    tipCustomEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipcustomeditText);
    totalCustomEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.totaltcustomeditText);
    billEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.billeditText1);
    billEditText.addTextChangedListener(billEditTextWatcher);
    SeekBar customSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.customSeekBar);
    customSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListner);
    customTipTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTipTextView);    
}
private void updateStandard()
{
    double tenPercentTip= currentBillTotal * .1;
    double tenPercentTotal = currentBillTotal+tenPercentTip;
    total10EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f,tenPercentTotal"));
    double fifteenPercentTip= currentBillTotal * .15;
    double fifteenPercentTotal= currentBillTotal+fifteenPercentTip;
    double twentyPercentTip= currentBillTotal * .20;
    double twentyPercentTotal= currentBillTotal+twentyPercentTip;
    tip10EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f",tenPercentTip));

    tip15EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f",fifteenPercentTip));
    total15EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f,fifteenPercentTotal"));
    tip20EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f",twentyPercentTip));
    total20EditText.setText(String.format("%.02f,twentyPercentTotal"));
}
private void updateCustom()
{
    customTipTextView.setText(currentCustomPercent+"%");
    double customTipAmount=currentBillTotal*currentCustomPercent*.01;
    tipCustomEditText.setText(String.format("%.02f",customTipAmount));
    double customTotalAmount=currentBillTotal+customTipAmount;
    totalCustomEditText.setText(String.format("%.02f",customTotalAmount));
}
@Override
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
   {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

      outState.putDouble(BILL_TOTAL, currentBillTotal);
      outState.putInt(CUSTOM_PERCENT, currentCustomPercent);
   } 
private OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListner=new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        currentCustomPercent=seekBar.getProgress();
        updateCustom();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub1

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
private TextWatcher billEditTextWatcher=new TextWatcher()
{

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        try
        {
            currentBillTotal=Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            currentBillTotal=0.0;
        }
        updateStandard();
        updateCustom();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

so in eclipse it says in the update standard lines that the variables are not used the tenPercentTotal,fifteenPercentTotal and twentyPercentTotal idk why it says that they are used in the next lines below it pls help this exact program worked before i right clicked my project and selected export android app option that messed up many things idk what happened.

Comment: Your closing " is in the wrong position for some of your String.format calls

Answer (score 0):

You're spelling their names out in the formatting strings instead of actually using them as arguments in the String#format() method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is not wrong (maybe refresh project + Validate if hes outdated).

Assigning values to variable does not count as usage.